# Unsure of how to get started with using NLP for analyzing user feedback

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have ~138k records of user feedback that I'd like to analyze to understand broad patterns in what our users are most often saying. Each one has a rating between 1-5 stars, so I don't need to do any sort of sentiment analysis. I'm mostly interested in splitting the dataset into >=4 stars to see what we're doing well and <= 3 stars to see what we need to improve upon.

One key problem I'm running into is that I expect to see a lot of n-grams. Some of these I know, like "HOV lane", "carpool lane", "detour time", "out of my way", etc. But I also want to detect common bi- and tri-grams programmatically. I've been playing around with Spacy a bit, but it doesn't seem to have any capability to do analysis on the corpus level, only on the document level.

Ideally my pipeline would look something like this (I think):

1. Import a list of known n-grams into the tokenizer
2. Process each string into a tokenized document, removing punctuation,
   stopwords, etc, while respecting the known n-grams during
   tokenization (ie, "HOV lane" should be a single noun token)
3. Identify the most common bi- and tri- grams in the corpus that I
   missed
4. Re-tokenize using the found n-grams
5. Split by rating (>=4 and <=3)
6. Find the most common topics for each split of data in the corpus

I can't seem to find a single tool, or even a collection of tools, that will allow me to do what I want here. Am I approaching this the wrong way somehow? Any pointers on how to get started would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bingo State of the art results for your problem!**

Its called - Zero-Short learning.
State-of-the-art NLP models for text classification without annotated data.

For Code and details read the blog - https://joeddav.github.io/blog/2020/05/29/ZSL.html

Let me know if it works for you or for any other help.

Comment: So this doesn't accomplish my proposed pipeline, but I think it basically gets me to the same result. The live demo is basically an auto-tagger, given a list of user-input tags, which is pretty close to what I'm trying to get. The code looks *very* simple too! I'll definitely play around with this, thanks!

Comment: Please consider up-voting it.

Answer (score 0):

[VADER](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) tool is perfect with sentiment analysis and NLP based applications.

I think the proposed workflow is fine with this case study. Closely work with your feature extraction as it matters a lot.
Most of the time **tri-grams** make a sound sense on these use cases.

Using [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) would be a better decision as SpaCy's rules-based match engines and components not only help you to find what the terms and sentences are searching for but also allow you to access the tokens inside a text and its relationships compared with regular expressions.

Comment: I don't think VADER is actually what I want here. As I said in the original post, each one of my records has a rating between 1-5 stars, so I don't need to do any sort of sentiment analysis. I already know if the user had a positive or negative experience based on the star rating. What I'm trying to determine is the most common reasons *why* users have a positive or negative experience. VADER only seems to determine if a particular document was positive or negative in sentiment, but not the reason why (ie, determine the topic).